# On the in-game "watch", is the white needle's scale 400 km?

Tags: one-way-heroics

You know the watch in the top right hand corner?

[image]

In Easy mode, the white hand starts at noon and ticks down as you reach the Evil Lord, who waits for you at around the 400 km marker.

Does that mean that, now that I'm playing the Mission to Revive the Force Knight at Hard difficulty, since the white needle points at 3 o' clock, my next altar is 100 km away?

Comment: Bonus points: if the white needle is counting down time instead of distance (e.g. the "standard" mission on any difficulty other than Easy), how many days is the scale of the clock?